# Android Studio Render Title and Settings Missing

Tags: android, rendering, settings, title

So I'm just making my first steps in Android Development and I got this problem I can't solve.

[image]

In the rendering part in Android Studio my default blank app doesn't show the title of the application or the default setting button but they do appear if I load the app on my phone or on the simulator. This is very weird and frustrating.

Why is this happening?

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, please open the `activity_main.xml` file. You will see there:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

It's your main activity toolbar, which screenshot you put there above. It has id, but it don't have any title. You can *change it programmatically*, but well, you won't see *until* you run an app on emulator or device.

This `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` view comes from Google's Material Design. You can learn more about from ths site:

[Introduction - Material Design - Google Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

or by attending this free Udacity course:

[Material Design for Android Developers](https://www.udacity.com/course/material-design-for-android-developers--ud862)

It allows you to create your own toolbar from a scratch (if you don't like existing). Take a look at this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="That's great app!"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This changed view is also a toolbar with given name, but instead of Toolbar I used here `LinearLayout` with one `TextView` item.

I don't know if I answer your question, but please experimentize a bit with my changed code by adding for example an `ImageView` which would be a logo of your app or icon of settings.